# How to query two values inside an array in Firebase firestore, where one value is indexed after the other one?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to query through an array of string values in firebase firestore which should contain two strings **a** and **b** BUT string **b** has to be listed after string **a**?

**Example:**
I have two string values I would like to query for:

```
a = "12345"
b = "67890"
```

And I have stored multiple documents in firebase firestore which could look like this:

```
document1 = {
    id: "randomId1",
    // ...other stuff
    array: ["12345","345", "67890"]
}

document2 = {
    id: "randomId2",
    // ...other stuff
    array: ["67890","345","12345"]
}
```

Now I only want to get **document1** in my query results, because value **b** is listed after value **a** in the array section. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do such queries in firestore, you can only define if it has this value or not.

Possible solutions:

1. Store a boolean inside your document which defines if this doc suits your needs.
2. Load all documents that have both values and check for their order on the client side.
3. Probably you should restructure your database, it is usually help in such cases.